# Using xsl:param for a xpath select

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I got a complex xml file and need to select some nodes from it with parameter from the command line.

The transformation should show all services from time x to time y

here we go with my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:param name="Time_from"/>
    <xsl:param name="Time_to"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Services/Service[(@time mod 1000000) &lt; number($Time_from)
                                       and (@time mod 1000000) &gt; number($Time_to)
                                            ]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SelectedServices>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </SelectedServices>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The time is in string format YYYYMMDDHHmmss, thats why I use mod to find the correct nodes.

But when I do the transform nothing is selected, if I replace the $time_from $time_to variables with the values I find my nodes.

Can someone help me?

XML File would look like

```
<Services>
  <Service time="20140410060000">Service Value 1</Service>
  <Service time="20140410071300">Service Value 2</Service>
</Services>
```

Comment: An input XML file would be helpful!

Comment: Your XSLT says `version="2.0"`, please state if you use an XSLT 2.0 processor where we can hopefully use proper date or dateTime value comparison. Also please show the exact values you pass in for the parameters.

Comment: This sounds like a question about supplying parameters to whatever tool you're using to run this transformation. Have you tried simply outputting their values to verify that they are being successfully passed?

Comment: I am using Eclipse EE for transformation therefore its Xalan 2.7.1